# Android How to pass interface reference by intent

Tags: android, interface, parcelable

ProgressUpdateListener:

```
public interface ProgressUpdateListener  { 
        public void on_update(int downloaded_size);
}
```

FileDownloader

```
public class FileDownloader implements Parcelable {
    ProgressUpdateListener listener;

    public FileDownloader(ProgressUpdateListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }


   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
     // how to write listener?
   }
}
```

My question is how to deal with the listener reference in writeToParcel..??

Comment: Interface can't be instantiated it can only be implemented, You need to implement this interface in your class.

Comment: You can let the concreate instance also implements Serializable, put the object inside a bundle, and wrote it in the Parcelable. I ma not sure if it works

Answer (score -2):

Interface can't be instantiated it can only be implemented, You need to implement this interface in your class

Do like this, and add un-implemented methods as well

```
 public class FileDownloader implements Parcelable,ProgressUpdateListener  {
```